# Error on defining Key:=Range("") for table filter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, listobject, excel-tables

I'm working on a code to filter my table, but I'm struggling to set the 'Key:=Range("")' , so far I've tested a code without setting Dims and it works, but I want a more pratical approach, so the code will work in all worksheets (active worksheet) in my workbook.
Error im getting: Method range of object _'Global' failed. Error 1004

So on resume, im new on VBA and dont now how to set MyTable(Tbl) on the 'Key:=Range("Tbl[[#All],[Column1]]")

```
Sub MAKE_FILTER()
   
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim Tbl As Object
Set Tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)


    Tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    Tbl.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Tbl[[#All],[DANFE]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Tbl.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Tbl.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Tbl[[#All],[Nº NF-e]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Tbl.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Without DIMs:

```
Sub Macro1() 'without DIMs

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela14212255").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor 'ok
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOVEMBRO 2022").ListObjects("Tabela14212255").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear 'ok
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOVEMBRO 2022").ListObjects("Tabela14212255").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Tabela14212255[[#All],[DANFE]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOVEMBRO 2022").ListObjects("Tabela14212255"). _
        Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOVEMBRO 2022").ListObjects("Tabela14212255").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOVEMBRO 2022").ListObjects("Tabela14212255").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Tabela14212255[[#All],[Nº NF-e]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NOVEMBRO 2022").ListObjects("Tabela14212255"). _
        Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Key:=tbl.Listcolumns("Nº NF-e").Range`

Comment: Is the table named "Tbl" in the worksheet or is that just the name of the variable? For worksheet addresses, you need to use their Excel name, not their VBA codename

Comment: Tbl will be the first table of the current active worksheet > Example 'Tbl = TableXXXX' , so it is a variable, but if I use the VBA codename, this code will not work in my other worksheets

Comment: @Rory dude thank youuuu!! Worked the way i wanted, thank you very much!!! if you want to answer properly i will mark your answer as correct, in the comments i can just upvote hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Key:=tbl.Listcolumns("Nº NF-e").Range
```

to refer to the column by name.

Answer (score 1):

### Filter and Sort Tables (ListObjects)

```
Sub ApplyFilter()
   
    Dim Headers() As Variant: Headers = Array("DANFE", "No NF-e")
    
    ' Reference 'ActiveSheet' and 'ThisWorkbook'.
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    If Not ws.Parent Is wb Then
        MsgBox "This only works for worksheets in the workbook containing " _
            & "this code named '" & wb.Name & "' and located in '" _
            & wb.Path & "'.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the table.
    
    Dim lo As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next
        Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1) ' the first table
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If lo Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet '" & ws.Name & "' doesn't contain any tables.", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Filter and sort.
    
    With lo
        
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then ' autofilter arrows are turned on
            ' Clear all filters.
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        
        .Range.AutoFilter 1, RGB(255, 255, 0), xlFilterCellColor
        
        Dim lc As ListColumn, n As Long
        
        For n = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
            ' Reference the column.
            On Error Resume Next
                Set lc = .ListColumns(Headers(n))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If lc Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "No column named '" & Headers(n) & "' in the table " _
                    & "named '" & .Name & "' of worksheet '" _
                    & .Parent.Name & "'.", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
            ' Sort by the column.
            With .Sort
                With .SortFields
                    .Clear
                    .Add2 lc.Range, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
                End With
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
            Set lc = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        Next n
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time on this code, it worked perfectly too!